# "Optional that can be string" or "String that is optional"?

Tags: swift, option-type

Going through the latest Stanford iOS development course videos (which now use Swift rather than Objective-C), the presenter seems to make a big deal when first introducing optionals (lecture 1, in the initial calculator demo).

The line of code was something like:

```
let digit = sender.currentTitle
```

where `sender` is a `UIButton`, and it's rightly pointed out that the type of `digit` is set to `String?`.

Now I understand the *concept* of optionals having used nullable types in C# (and manually-created variants in C using structures).

But the presenter states *emphatically* that you should consider the `String?` type to be optional, and that it may hold a string. You should *not* think of it as a string that may be `nil`.

To me, the distinction seems artificial unless you're talking about how it's implemented under the covers. As far as the language itself is concerned, I'm ambivalent as to which way you would describe it.

But, since I'm only getting started in the language, my question is this. Is there some reason why it's more correct to consider it one way or the other?

I'm not looking for opinion, rather wondering if there's some basic language feature or aspect I haven't got to yet, that really *requires* us to consider the type as "optional but may be a string".

Comment: What's confusing here is that in ObjC `nil` means 'doesn't point to anything', and in Swift it means 'points to the `.None` enum value of the `Option` type'. You'll need to mentally translate between them when you're dealing with either language.

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the presenter states emphatically that you should consider the
>   String? type to be optional, and that it may hold a string.

Yes.  An optional is a distinct type.  It is a container that may be empty (`nil`) or may hold the type (e.g. `String`) that it is named for.  You must open the container (unwrap the optional) to use it.

> You should not think of it as a string that may be nil.

Yes.  If a function takes a `String` as an argument, you can't pass it a variable of type `String?`.  You must unwrap that optional before you use it, that is, you need to open the container and remove the contents (the `String`) if the container (optional) is not empty (`nil`).

Comment: Actually, the inability to use `String` and `String?` interchangeably is a good point, indicating that the latter is _not_ a variant on the former (a string that can be nil). But my first thought that they are then two totally unrelated types is a no-go as well since they are related in the sense you can unbox one from the other. Good answer.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently optionals are implemented as Swift enums. One of the enum values is .Some (with an associated value of generic type T) and the .None value (where the value is fixed at nil, and there is no associated value.

Thus an optional isn't a pointer that can point to address zero, it is an enum that has 2 states, a none state, and a state that stores some other value. When it is in it's None state, it doesn't hold ANY value.

The distinction becomes clear if you think of using an optional to store an Int.

The nil value almost always is saved as a zero.

Lets say we have a var:

```
var anInt: Int?
```

So if an Int can save a value, or nil, then what would be the difference between

```
anInt = 0
```

and

```
anInt = nil
```

Answer: No difference. If nil is a value, and that value is zero, you can't distinguish between no value and a zero value.

However, with an optional, there IS a difference.

You can say:

```
anInt = 0;
if (anInt == nil)
{ 
  println("anInt has no value"
}
else
{
   println("anInt has the value \(anInt)")
}
```

And what will be displayed is

> anInt has the value 0.

If instead you assign

```
anInt = nil
```

Then what will be displayed is

> anInt has no value